# Arduino Leonardo avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

Tags: arduino

Hola buenas noches a todos estoy ocupando para un proyecto la placa de arduino leonardo, aclaro no es la generica es la que es hecha en Italia, esta la he ocupado en windows sin nungun problema pero debido a las condiciones del proyecto debo de correr el IDE en ubuntu, estoy ocupando la version 20.04 de 64 bits, he intentado subir mis programas a la placa sin exito alguno, algunas de las cosas que he realizado son las siguientes

-resetear la placa antes de subir el proyecto

tambien he habilitado el puerto d ela siguiente manera

- ls /dev/ttyACM0
- la -l /dev/ttyACM0
- sudo usermod -a -G dialout neox

pero me sigue marcado el mismo error a continuación lo pongo detallamente

```
/snap/arduino/41/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /snap/arduino/41/hardware -hardware /home/neox/snap/arduino/41/.arduino15/packages -tools /snap/arduino/41/tools-builder -tools /snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -tools /home/neox/snap/arduino/41/.arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /snap/arduino/41/libraries -libraries /home/neox/snap/arduino/current/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:leonardo -vid-pid=2341_8036 -ide-version=10813 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_167499 -warnings=none -build-cache /tmp/arduino_cache_28125 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7.path=/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -verbose /home/neox/Desktop/sketch_nov03a/sketch_nov03a.ino
/snap/arduino/41/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /snap/arduino/41/hardware -hardware /home/neox/snap/arduino/41/.arduino15/packages -tools /snap/arduino/41/tools-builder -tools /snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -tools /home/neox/snap/arduino/41/.arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /snap/arduino/41/libraries -libraries /home/neox/snap/arduino/current/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:leonardo -vid-pid=2341_8036 -ide-version=10813 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_167499 -warnings=none -build-cache /tmp/arduino_cache_28125 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7.path=/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr -verbose /home/neox/Desktop/sketch_nov03a/sketch_nov03a.ino
Using board 'leonardo' from platform in folder: /snap/arduino/41/hardware/arduino/avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /snap/arduino/41/hardware/arduino/avr
Detecting libraries used...
/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 "-DUSB_MANUFACTURER=\"Unknown\"" "-DUSB_PRODUCT=\"Arduino Leonardo\"" -I/snap/arduino/41/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/snap/arduino/41/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /tmp/arduino_build_167499/sketch/sketch_nov03a.ino.cpp -o /dev/null -DARDUINO_LIB_DISCOVERY_PHASE
Generating function prototypes...
/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 "-DUSB_MANUFACTURER=\"Unknown\"" "-DUSB_PRODUCT=\"Arduino Leonardo\"" -I/snap/arduino/41/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/snap/arduino/41/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /tmp/arduino_build_167499/sketch/sketch_nov03a.ino.cpp -o /tmp/arduino_build_167499/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp -DARDUINO_LIB_DISCOVERY_PHASE
/snap/arduino/41/tools-builder/ctags/5.8-arduino11/ctags -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives /tmp/arduino_build_167499/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
Compiling sketch...
/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 "-DUSB_MANUFACTURER=\"Unknown\"" "-DUSB_PRODUCT=\"Arduino Leonardo\"" -I/snap/arduino/41/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/snap/arduino/41/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /tmp/arduino_build_167499/sketch/sketch_nov03a.ino.cpp -o /tmp/arduino_build_167499/sketch/sketch_nov03a.ino.cpp.o
Compiling libraries...
Compiling core...
Using precompiled core: /tmp/arduino_cache_28125/core/core_arduino_avr_leonardo_7b405e04c0f46b59ea54710ef25537f3.a
Linking everything together...
/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega32u4 -o /tmp/arduino_build_167499/sketch_nov03a.ino.elf /tmp/arduino_build_167499/sketch/sketch_nov03a.ino.cpp.o /tmp/arduino_build_167499/../arduino_cache_28125/core/core_arduino_avr_leonardo_7b405e04c0f46b59ea54710ef25537f3.a -L/tmp/arduino_build_167499 -lm
/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 /tmp/arduino_build_167499/sketch_nov03a.ino.elf /tmp/arduino_build_167499/sketch_nov03a.ino.eep
/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom /tmp/arduino_build_167499/sketch_nov03a.ino.elf /tmp/arduino_build_167499/sketch_nov03a.ino.hex
/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-size -A /tmp/arduino_build_167499/sketch_nov03a.ino.elf
Sketch uses 3494 bytes (12%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28672 bytes.
Global variables use 153 bytes (5%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2407 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2560 bytes.
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port /dev/ttyACM0
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM0, } / {/dev/ttyACM0, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM0, } / {/dev/ttyACM0, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM0, } / {/dev/ttyACM0, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM0, } / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {/dev/ttyACM0, } => {/dev/ttyACM0, }
Found upload port: /dev/ttyACM0
/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/arduino_build_167499/sketch_nov03a.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/snap/arduino/41/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/neox/snap/arduino/41/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : butterfly
         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
Found programmer: Id = ""; type =
```

ya he probado tambien instalar manual y la que se instala con el snap pero aun asi no he podido subir mi codigo a la tarjeta, para evitar errores de dedo he subido un programa en blanco ya que me ha pasado que luego algo mal y marca ese tipo de errores
muchas gracias espero y alguien me pueda ayudar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es un problema común con Arduino. Paso 1) asegurate de que no haya otro programa ocupando la puerta serial/usb. Paso 2) Desconecta/reconecta el Arduino.

Comment: ya he cambiado  el conector en los diferentes puertos y tambien de cable pero aun asi no he podido igual he cambiado la version, despues de un buen rato me arroja el siguiente mensaje que igual he buscado por ese punto **programmer did not respod to command: exit bootloader **

Comment: Estoy bastante seguro de que tu problema proviene de usar `snap`. Es un *contenedor* de aplicaciones, y `99.99%` seguro que restringe el acceso a `/dev` de algún modo. Échale un ojo a [su documentación](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapcraft-app-and-service-metadata), y, si no consigues nada, instala el IDE fuera de `snap`.